# jQuery button fire not working if put before PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

For some reason, my jQuery code is ignoring the button generated by PHP (IF the php is done inline).

This is the code that does not work (the jQuery click is not firing):

```
$('button').click(function(){
alert("CLICKED");

var btnNum = $(this).attr('value');
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$.post("../update_rsvp.php", {id : btnNum}).done(function( data ) {
    var spanId = "#rsvpd-"+btnNum;
    $(spanId).html("YES");

  });

});
```

Well, technically the code works. However, ONLY if I generate my button BEFORE my html headers. If i generate it after the headers, then it does not work. This is he php code:

```
        <?php 
        if( $cnt > 0 )
        {   
            $where = array(
                "code" => $code
            );

            $what = array('inv_id','first_name', 'last_name', 'rsvpd');

            $count = $db->count($where, 'invited');
            $result = $db->select_where($where, 'invited' , $what);

            echo '<br />';
            echo '<br />';
            echo "You have $count invitations: <br />";
            echo "<ul>";
            echo "";
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                if($row['rsvpd'] == 1)
                {
                    $rsvpd = 'YES';
                    $disabled = 'disabled';

                }else{
                    $rsvpd = 'NO';
                    $disabled = '';
                }
                echo "<li>
                <div class='tbl-row'>
                <div class='tbl-col'><p>".$row['first_name']."&nbsp;</p></div>
                <div class='tbl-col'><p>".$row['last_name']."&nbsp; </p></div>
                <div class= 'tbl-col'><span id='rsvpd-".$row['inv_id']."'><p>".$rsvpd."&nbsp;</p></span></div>
                <div class='tbl-col'>
                    <button value='".$row['inv_id']."' $disabled >RSVP</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";

        }
        else
        {

            echo "You have NO invitations!";

        }

        ?>
```

Any help/suggestion is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `event delegation` in this context,

```
$(document).on('click','button',function(){
  //your code here.
});
```

Please read [**here**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to know more about `event delegation.`

Comment: @down voter: Can you please tell me the reason for your vote.? so that I could correct it in futue.?

Comment: That's beautiful! Worked flawlessly.. Another solution was to put the code after by body tags (which i know is not recommended).. Since My rep is low, I cannot upvote you, but certainly would. Thank you!

Comment: @abbondanza But you can accept it as your answer. :) Glad to help.!

Answer (score 0):

Where is your JS relative to your button?
Try it after your button, or wrap your script in a call to:

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function(){
    // your js
});
```